# How to select one particular view from group of view's?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener, custom-view

For an app I need to develop, I need to be able to `select one view` from `ViewGroup` when user `long press` on the `view` have to popup an alert dialog, from that i will select options depending on the requirement, those are delete view and change background color for that particular view. I am creating different custom view's ( Custom view extends from View) and It has Touchlistener's. Dynamically attaching those view's to layout (RelativeLayout). Let us assume my layout having 3 views.

**My questions:**

- I want to select one view from the list of available view's on the layout.
- How to restrict the Custom view size instead of occupying full parent view.

**I am facing Problem's like this:** Look at this image if i set background color for custom view it look like this, Actually i was set for layout background color White here custom view occupies full screen. so, unable to see parent background color. Here problem with customview size, unable to restrict the customview size rather than occupying full parent view. even if i touch outside of my custom view, the touch listeners of custom view was triggering. i want to restrict those touch listeners upto my customview only..

[image].

**Main Requirement:**
Finally i want to be achieve like this below image, Now i am able to add more custom view's to layout,but unable to delete selected one. When i long press on any one of the view from the layout, it should popup one alert dialog with two buttons, if i select one selected view should be delete for another selection background color change.

[image]

**RelaventCode:** i am adding view to layout like this.

```
findViewById(R.id.line).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CustomView drawView = new CustomView(context);
        frame.addView(drawView);
   }
});
```

and this is the customview :

```
public class CustomView extends View {

public CustomView (Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
private void init() {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint pai = new Paint();         
    Path path = new Path();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    path.lineTo(50, 100);       
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    path.moveTo(Top_Point.x, Top_Point.y);
    path.lineTo(Right_Point.x, Right_Point.y);
    path.lineTo(Left_Point.x, Left_Point.y);
    path.lineTo(Top_Point.x, Top_Point.y);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, Inner_Paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Top_Point.x, Top_Point.y, Right_Point.x, Right_Point.y,
            Lines_Paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Right_Point.x, Right_Point.y, Left_Point.x,
            Left_Point.y, Lines_Paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Left_Point.x, Left_Point.y, Top_Point.x, Top_Point.y,
            Lines_Paint);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {     
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        PointF NewP = new PointF(0, 0);
        NewP.x = event.getX();
        NewP.y = event.getY();
        if (TopTouchArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_TOP;
        } else if (RightTouchArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_RIGHT;
        } else if (LeftTouchArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_LEFT;
        } else if (a) {
            Translate_Point.x = event.getX();
            Translate_Point.y = event.getY();
            currentTouch = Inner_Touch;
            return true; // Return false if user touches none of the
                            // corners
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        switch (currentTouch) {
        case TOUCH_TOP:
               /*  ------ */
        case TOUCH_RIGHT:
               /*   ----- */
            invalidate();
            return true;
        case TOUCH_LEFT:
         /* ------ */
            invalidate();
            return true;
        case Inner_Touch:
            /* ------ */
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }           
        return false; 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:         
        switch (currentTouch) {
        case TOUCH_TOP:
            /* ----- */
            return true;
        case TOUCH_RIGHT:
            /* ----- */
            return true;
        case TOUCH_LEFT:
            /* ----- */
            return true;
        case Inner_Touch:
            /* ----- */
            invalidate();  
        return true;
        }           
        return false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing the relevant code. Maybe someone will _guess_ what is happening, but maybe not...

Comment: @Sam i was updated my Question with relevant codes. if it's not in clear let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `onSizeChanged` or `onMeasure` methods to let your `ViewGroup` know your view's size. And make sure that your view's width and height are both `WRAP_CONTENT`.

About touch event - problem here is that your view size is matching parent size, so it intercepts all touch events (since it returns `true` in `onTouchEvent`).

And here is [a great tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Comment: I will change those custom view size dynamically by pulling points on custom view using Touch Listener's..

Comment: @RajaReddyP then you should change view size exactly in `onMeasure` method. So, in your touch listener you're setting required attributes and force view to call `onMeasure` (but do not call it directly). Through this method you're a telling your layout how big your view is.

Comment: I not sure how to set those function, i have no experience on Customview's.

Comment: i searched in google i found this, un-able to trigger long press because of touch-liseners in that view, i am not sure either it's correct or not..

Comment: See the tutorial in my answer. It's step by step tutorial about custom views.

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnLongClickListener to the customview before adding it to the view group.

To help identify the view at a higher level, you may want to set an identifier on the view using setTag("id", id);

Comment: i tried like this, first un-able to select one particular view from the list of view's. that was the main problem

Comment: Do you mean there is a user interface problem or that you had trouble determining which view was clicked? To determine which view you clicked you retrieve the identifier from view.getTag("id");

Comment: not UI problem, unable to select a view from group of views.let us assume i have 3 custom view's on layout now i want to select a view when i long press on view. even i was added long press code for each customviews it's not triggering, always it call touchlisteners only.

Comment: so the viewgroup that you've added the customview to has a touchlistener?

Comment: how can i achieve if i add touch listeners to main activity. i tried by add long press on main activity, but not succeed.

Comment: I wouldn't add any touch listeners at all. If you just want long clicks on your custom views, just add onLongClickListener to the custom views.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the view you add is too big and fills it's parent.
Isn't it sufficient to do something like

```
TwoPointsDraw drawView = new TwoPointsDraw(context);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
drawView.setLayoutParams(lp)
frame.addView(drawView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this project, it might be helpful => [Android multitouch controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/checkout), a simple multitouch pinch zoom library for Android.

Here is another [example](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/).

Comment: I am not looking for multi touch, if i have some view how to select one from that..

Comment: There is one library MTController and one example MTPhotoSortr. Just run this example in emulator and check. There are 2-3 images in one view and it selects as you touch it. So this logic might be helpful to you to implement what you want.